PhpStorm inspections on __call magic methods without knowing the name of the dynamic functions
The short version of this is, I want PhpStorm to know the datatype returned by a dynamic function call that is handled by __call. There is no way to know the name of the dynamic functions reasonably because __call is in my code, a "framework" of sorts, and the dynamic function names are created at runtime by developers using my class. My class will not have access to those names  so adding @method wont work. I understand the other developers can add their own annotations, but my question is how to do this without requiring them to do that.
So, the scenario; I know some of this will seem silly or not flushed out. There's a lot going on in this code so I'm trying to break it down into something simple but that is still mostly analogous to the real code.
I have a database class that has several methods setup to call different stored procedures in the database. There are different methods because there are several standard architectures for our stored procedures. So, something like this:
class Database {
   function method_a($proc_name) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_a();
   }
   function method_b($proc_name) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_b();
   }
   function method_c($proc_name) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_c();
   }
}

The other developers who use this class put declarations for there stored procedures into a text file. It has the name of the stored procedure, its args, and what architecture method it uses (a, b or c). The database class parses that text file, and stores all the procedure names and their types (a, b or c) in a local array. Then it implements the __call function so the user can directly call their stored procedures by name, something like this:
class Database {
   private $procs;

   function __construct()
   {
      //open and parse text file into $procs
   }

   function method_a($proc_name, $args) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_a();
   }
   function method_b($proc_name, $args) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_b();
   }
   function method_c($proc_name, $args) {
      //call $proc_name
      return new return_c();
   }

   function __call($function, $args) {   
      switch ($this->procs[$function]) {
         case "A":
            return $this->method_a($function);
         case "B":
            return $this->method_b($function);
         case "C":
            return $this->method_c($function);
      }
   }
}

So if the developer puts this in their text file:
A some_proc();

then if they call this:
$return = $databse->some_proc($args);

it will actually be calling
$return = $database->method_a("some_proc", $args);

How can I tell PhpStorm what the return type of $return is? I can't use @method in my Database class because I don't know what the function names the developer will put in their text file.
I want to avoid the developer having to explicitly annotate the type, that's kind of the whole question really--how do I do this in a central location.
There's only 3 return types, so I wouldn't mind the inspection listing all 3 types as possible. For example, I tried this on the class:
@method return_a|return_b|return_c __call(string $name, array $args)

but that didn't work, I also tried doing the similar thing with this above the actual __call method:
@return return_a|return_b|return_c 

Is this even possible?

I can't tell, but can you guarantee that only A, B and C are called, and that they return return_a, return_b and return_c respectively? If so I'd think something like this would work: https://3v4l.org/9v6HO

Hmm... I guess not, because they could put some_proc. In that case, I don't think this is possible. If your developers get to invent their own method names via a text file, I don't think you can type-hint against that.
